# python3 write a file's content into a yaml

Tags: python, file, yaml

I'm trying to write a python3 code to iterate on YAML files that look like this, for example:

my_yaml.yaml

```
input:
    program:
        filename: 01-02.c
```

look for 01-02.c file, read it and write it back to the YAML file that will look like this

my_yaml.yaml

```
input:
    program: |-
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include<stdio.h>

        int main(void)
        {
            int bobDylan = 50;
            int ummKulthum = 100;
            int janisJoplin = 10;
            int johnnyCash = 90;
            // duduTasa was an unused variable!
                                                                        // bobDylan | ummKulthum | janisJoplin | johnnyCash
                                                                        // --------   -----------   -------------   ---------------
            johnnyCash /= 3;                                            //    50    |     100     |       10      |        30
            bobDylan = ummKulthum + janisJoplin++ * 3;                  //   130    |     100     |       11      |        30
            bobDylan += --johnnyCash + janisJoplin + ummKulthum;        //    70    |     100     |       11      |       29

            printf("How many roads must a man walk down before you can call him a man?\n");
            printf("The answer my friend, is %d\n", bobDylan);
            return 0;
        }
```

Here is how I'm reading the YAML file:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as stream:
    try:
        data_loaded = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print('yaml loading error for ' + repr(file_path) + ' ' + repr(exc))
        return

return data_loaded
```

I've managed to read the file like so:

```
program_content = open(filename_to_replace, 'r').read()
data_loaded['input'][key] = '|- ' + program_content
```

but when I write back, using this:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as yml:
   yaml.dump(data_loaded, yml, default_flow_style=False)
```

the end results looks like this:

```
input:
  program: "|- #include<stdio.h>\n#include<string.h>\n\n#define STR_LEN 20\n#define\
    \ LITTLE_A_CHAR 'a'\n#define LITTLE_Z_CHAR 'z'\n#define BIG_A_CHAR 'A'\n#define\
    \ BIG_Z_CHAR 'Z'\n\nvoid myFgets(char str[], int n);\n\nint main(void)\n{\n\t\
    char str[STR_LEN] = { 0 };\n\tchar smallStr[STR_LEN] = { 0 }, bigStr[STR_LEN]\
    \ = { 0 };\n\tint ind = 0, sInd = 0, bInd = 0;\n\n\tprintf(\"Enter a string with\
    \ upper and lower case letters: \");\n\tmyFgets(str, STR_LEN);\n\n\tfor (ind =\
    \ 0; ind < (int)strlen(str); ind++)\n\t{\n\t\tif (str[ind] >= LITTLE_A_CHAR &&\
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your complete code. currently, you're assigning something to `input_data[key]` but then dump `data_loaded` which we have never seen before. Prepending `|- ` to the data is definitely wrong, it's not part of the content.

Comment: @flyx, thanks, added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the output format by just prepending `|-`:

```
data_loaded['input'][key] = '|- ' + program_content
```

You should add to your imports:

```
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import PreservedScalarString
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
```

and then replace that line by:

```
data_loaded['input'][key] = PreservedScalarString(program_content)
```